# remove last comma

Tags: php, string

I want to remove "," from the given string in $code variable but the result is showing **"Array"** in $code1 instead of balakrishnan.  How to rectify the error.

```
$code="balakrishnan,";
$code1 = explode(',', $code);
```

Comment: Yes, `str_replace` or `rtrim` will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You don't want `explode()` which splits a string up into an array. You want [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string:</s>

$code1 = str_replace(',', '', $code);

or, in your use case, [`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) would work, too:

$code1 = rtrim($code, ',');

**edit**

You do want to use `explode()`, you just need to access the variables correctly.

```
$code1 = explode(',',"balakrishnan,kumar,vinoth");
echo $code1[0]; // prints "balakrishnan"
```

Comment: actually my string like "balakrishnan,kumar,vinoth" how to remove , only

Comment: Then use `str_replace()` only

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason you still want to use explode, just do:

```
echo $code1[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dozen ways to do this. If you use `explode()`, also use `implode()` again.

```
$code="balakrishnan,";
$code1 = implode('',explode(',', $code));
```

```
$code="balakrishnan,";
$code1 = str_replace(',','', $code);
```

```
$code="balakrishnan,";
$code1 = substr($code,0,-1);
```

etc...

I would say, go with my last solution, because in the future you might have other commas in the middle of your string which you might want to keep.